# "Double-array" in Javascriptt

Tags: javascript

Actually, I have no idea what this called.
I want to do something like this Python-snippet in Javascript.

Thanks in advance!

```
array = {'http://facebook.com' : 'facebook',
'https://twitter.com' : 'twitter',
'https://google.com' : 'google'}

for domain, name in array.items():
    print 'The name of '+domain+' is '+name
```

Edit, sorry for my misstake with , and :
Was to tired for coding...

Comment: Folks - This is not Javascript and not a question.

Comment: The typical idiom would be an array of arrays or array of objects.

Comment: This isn't a valid python either.

Comment: That looks to me like a one-dimensional array of six elements, but pretty much every language that supports arrays and loops will let you process the elements two at a time. What have you tried so far?

Comment: In python that's called a dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an object:

```
var obj = {
    "facebook":"http://facebook.com",
    "twitter":"https://twitter.com",
    "google":"https://google.com"
}, name, loc;
for( name in obj) {
    loc = obj[name];
    console.log("The name of "+loc+" is "+name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first, your python code is incorrect.
I assume you meant this:

```
array = {'http://facebook.com': 'facebook',
'https://twitter.com': 'twitter',
'https://google.com': 'google'}

for domain, name in array.items():
    print 'The name of '+domain+' is '+name
```

this is called a dictionary.

now, in javascript the dictionary would be written the same as the above, with var infront of it:
 `var array ...`

and the for loop can be implemented in several ways.
my favorite:

```
var array = {
    'http://facebook.com': 'facebook',
    'https://twitter.com': 'twitter',
    'https://google.com': 'google'
};
Object.keys(array).forEach(function (key) {
    var domain = key,
        name = array[key];
    console.log('The name of '+domain+' is '+name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct equivalent to that in JavaScript. You can make an array and iterate through it by twos explicitly:

```
var array = ['http://facebook.com', 'facebook', ... ];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
  var domain = array[i];
  var name = array[i + 1];
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your snippet won't work, you need colons between the domains and the names, not commas.

Here's how you'd do that in javascript anyway:

```
var array = { "http://facebook.com":" facebook", "http://twitter.com": "twitter", "http://google.com": "Google"};
for (var domain in array) 
    console.log("the name of " + domain + " is " + array[domain]) ;
```

Comment: General hint: Don't write a `for .. in` loop without mentioning `hasOwnProperty`, especially to beginners.